# Weird Touch Screen Issue in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop

I am using a Lenovo G400s with Windows 8.1 x64 bit installed.

For the past two days, the touch screen isn't working properly. And by “not properly” I mean it is taking touch even when I'm not touching the screen. Two spots are being shown on the right of the screen, as shown in this image.

[image]

Due to this I can't use drag & clicks are being done constantly from touch. And I can only work after disabling the touch screen from the device manager.

This problem persists even after a reboot. The only way to get rid of these spots is to disable the touch screen.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue on my Lenovo, same place, too. Amazingly, it happened when I suddenly sneezed on the screen. What fixed it for me was under the Control Panel, I searched "touch" and "Tablet PC Settings" popped up second on the list. I did the steps for "Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input". After I did that, the spots were gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucy. I just forgot to update, I took my laptop to lenovo shop and got it fixed. Warranty helped me.